# Reading image to an array or matrix

Tags: c++, image, matrix

I am a newbie to c++. I am using it for image processing. My basic idea is to load an image and store the pixel values or intensities into a matrix or an array, so that i can perform further manipulations on them.

So, what i have done so far is

```
  QPixmap pixmap("lena.bmp");
  pixmap = pixmap.copy(512,512,128,128);
  pixmap = pixmap.scaled(32,32);
  QImage image = pixmap.toImage();
  QRgb col;

  int g;
  int width = pixmap.width();
  int height = pixmap.height();
  matrix<double> m(width,height);

for (int j = 0; j < m.size2(); j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size1(); i++)
    {
        col = image.pixel(i,j);
        g = qGray(col);

        image.setPixel(i,j,qRgb(g,g,g));
        m(i,j) = (image.pixel(i,j));

    }
}
```

for instance here i use Qpixmap in Qt for reading image and use boost to generate a matrix with the data.

But is there any other simpler way to read the image and to store it in a matrix? and perform manipulations and then display the new manipulated matrix as an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use OpenCV library, where images are by default represented as matrixes. OpenCV is very popular for image manipulation, and has many features. You can grab an example of loading image to matrix in OpenCV here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html

Comment: I donot want to use OpenCv. I only have the option to use either boost  or do it directly hrough c++

Comment: If you are going use only simple formats like bmp, you could just read the file, skip bitmap header (after reading important information about format of image) and work with bmp pixels data stored in array. Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format to see that bmp format is pretty simple. But I am not sure, if this makes it easier than using QImage or any other class to wrap image data. But this way you do not need Qt or boost.